# Looking for a heavy-tailed distribution

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions, distribution-tails

I want to find a probability distribution (given by its CDF $F$) such that
$$\liminf_{x \to \infty} \mathrm e^{\lambda x}(1-F(x)) = 0 \quad \text{for all } \lambda > 0$$
and
$$\limsup_{x \to \infty} \mathrm e^{\lambda x}(1-F(x)) = \infty \quad \text{for all } \lambda > 0.$$

The only thing that I could guess almost immediately is that this distribituion has to be heavy-tailed. Otherwise I have no clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to find a non-negative integrable function $f$ such that for all $c>1$, there are sequences $(x_n'),(x_n'')$ tending to infinity such that you have $c^{x_n'}\int_{x_n'}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ grows to infinity and  $c^{x_n''}\int_{x_n''}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ decays to zero.

The trick to deal with all $c$ at the same time is to make $\int_{x_n''}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ decay superexponentially, while making $\int_{x_n'}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ decay only subexponentially, for instance by ensuring that $\int_{x_n'}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\geq 1/(2x'_n)$, while $\int_{x_n''}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\leq 2^{-2^{x''_n}}$.

I'll leave the details to you, but with a clever choice of $(x_n')$ and $(x_n'')$, you can ensure that for $A=\bigcup_n (x_n',x_n'')$ (the union of intervals), this is true for the function $f(x)=1/x^2\cdot \mathbf 1_A(x)$ (where $\mathbf 1_A$ is the indicator function of $A$).

Then you only need to rescale $f$ to ensure that it is a pdf. $F$ can be recovered by integrating the resulting function, if needed.

Comment: Sorry, my calculus here is sketchy. With this choice of $f$ and ignoring $A$ this yields $c^x/x$ in the LHS. The lim sup is obvious. But how is the lim inf different from that and why is your sequence criterion equivalent to taking the lim inf?

Comment: The whole point is that taking the $A$ will allow you to make large "gaps" where $f$ is zero, which allows you to make the integral arbitrarily small. The criterion is equivalent to taking lim sup and lim inf pretty much by definition (modulo a mild application of axiom of choice, maybe - this is pretty much the same as equivalence of Cauchy/$\varepsilon-\delta$ and Heine/sequential definition of the limit).

Comment: I guess I'll look into the definition again. Your idea is that I should come up with the sequences and then get $A$ from that, right?

Comment: Yes, I think that is the easiest solution. You could probably cook up something without specifically using integration, but I think it's easier to think of it in these terms.

Comment: Oh, I neglected to include that: the sequences $(x_n'), (x_n'')$ should tend to infinity for the equivalence to be true. I modified the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Hm. Are the conditions on the sequences from the second paragraph sufficient? For $(x_n')$ it would suffice then to take $(n)$, right? For the second one I'm puzzled as to how such a sequence can even exist ...

Comment: Yes, if it wasn't for the $x_n''$. Essentially, you need to choose $x_n''$ sufficiently large so that the condition for $x_n'$ works, and then you need to choose $x_{n+1}'$ sufficiently large that the condition for $x_n''$ works and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. What exact conditions are you refering to in "choose $x_n''$ sufficiently large" and "choose $x_{n+1}$ sufficiently large"?

Comment: Of couse I meant $x_{n+1}'$. I think the question that my confusion arises from is: Is it possible (necessary?) to choose $(x_n')$ and $(x_n'')$ such that $c^{x_n'}\int_{x_n'}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \to \infty$ and $c^{x_n'}\int_{x_n''}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$ respectively hold true for every(!) non-negative, integrable $f$? Or should I think of $f$ as being arbitrary, but fixed?

Comment: Ok, I now tried the intuitive choice of $(x_n') = (n)$ and $(x_n'') = (n!)$. Then $c^{x_n'}\int_{x_n'}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = c^n/n \to \infty$ and $c^{x_n'}\int_{x_n''}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = c^n/n! \to 0$ for $f(x)=1/x^2$. This would yield $A = (3,\infty)$ which still kind of puzzles me. Also I still don't quite see the equivalence of the above conditions to the definition of lim sup and lim inf. Can you point me to any script, book or something where this is explained? In Wikipedia the definition is only given for accumulation points even ...

Comment: You should ensure that $x_{n+1}'\gg x_{n}''\gg x_{n}'$. I'm afraid I don't know any reference offhand.

Comment: Why is this necessary? Don't $c^{x_n'}\int_{x_n'}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ and $c^{x_n'}\int_{x_n''}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ are fulfilled by my choice, too? Why does it fail?

Comment: You put $c^n$ instead of $c^{n!}$ in one of the equations (besides swapping $x_n'$ and $x_n''$)

Comment: I see. So you meant $c^{x_n'}\int_{x_n''}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ decays to zero?

Comment: Oh, there is a typo. It should be double prime.